# Nhibernate HiLo on Azure

Tags: nhibernate, azure, hilo

Im trying to run create schema in Azure SQL but its failing because im using HiLo generated, Azure SQL requires CLUSTERED INDEX and HiLo table by default doesnt have any index, Anyone has tried HiLo in Azure before? Can anyone point me to to the right direction on what to do with this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally tried using it but in past when someone reported the following problem when using NHibernate statements for SQL Azure:

```
Heaps can not be replicated tables. Please create a clustered index for the table.
```

I remember the solution was to use NHibernate extension points as below:

```
public class MsSqlAzureDialect : MsSql2008Dialect
{
  public override string PrimaryKeyString
  {
     get { return "primary key CLUSTERED"; }
  }
}
```

As I haven't this solution, please try it and if this solves your problem that's fine otherwise please let me know and I will delete this answer.

Comment: This did solve the problem for entites and created a clusted index on the primry key. The issue is if using the HILO generator and the schema export tool, the hibernate_unique_key table is created without a clusted index, it does not have a primary key.

Comment: @longday: How did you solved your problem? I'm dying here because of this error. I dont want to do workarounds......